# Disable SSL/TLS certificate validation in Network.HTTP.Conduit

Tags: haskell, ssl, conduit, http-conduit

I use the [`http-conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) library version 2.0+ to fetch the contents from a `http://` URL:

```hs
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
myurl = ... -- Your URL goes here
main = do content <- simpleHttp myurl
          print $ content
```

When running this program, I get this error:

```
*** Exception: TlsException (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol
      ("certificate rejected: certificate is not allowed to sign another certificate",
        True,CertificateUnknown)))
```

As can be told from the error message, the problem is the inability of `Network.HTTP.Conduit` to validate the server certificate appropriately (in this case, there seem to be problems in the certificate chain)

How can I change the above code to ignore the certificate error (i.e. by not verifying certificates at all)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`simpleHttp` itself does not support this feature. You'll need to create a manager with modified `ManagerSettings` and then use that to fetch the URL.

Note that this code only applies for `http-conduits` version 2.0+ -- the library version 1 has a similar yet different API for this purpose.

```hs
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Network.Connection
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

myurl = ... -- Your URL goes here

-- | Get a new Manager that doesn't verify SSL certificates
noSSLVerifyManager :: IO Manager
noSSLVerifyManager = let tlsSettings = TLSSettingsSimple {
                            -- This is where we disable certificate verification
                            settingDisableCertificateValidation = True,
                            settingDisableSession=False,
                            settingUseServerName=True}
                     in newManager $ mkManagerSettings tlsSettings Nothing

-- | Download like with simpleHttp, but using an existing manager for the task
simpleHttpWithManager :: Manager -> String -> IO LB.ByteString
simpleHttpWithManager manager url = do url' <- parseUrl url
                                       fmap responseBody $ httpLbs url' manager

main = do manager <- noSSLVerifyManager
          content <- simpleHttpWithManager manager myurl
          print $ content
```

Note that you should only disable SSL certificate verification if absolutely neccessary, as it makes you vulnerable for man-in-the-middle attacks